# How can i create a list to select from for a property on my user control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties

I have a property on my user control called 'DataGridViewColumnType' and wondered if it was possible to make it a drop down and a list of column types to choose from? Even if it was just a list of strings would be good enough.

I have been playing with the attribute

```
<Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridColumnCollectionEditor, System.Design", GetType(UITypeEditor))>
```

But not having much luck and not sure it'd actually do what I want even if if I could get it to work. It just opens a column collection editor but the add button doesn't work and i haven't been able to get it to work so couldn't get any further.

So i thought if I can just create the list myself then somehow turn my property into a drop down that displays my list that would be fine. I just haven't done this before and can't seem to find much on how to achieve it.

Comment: If `DataGridViewColumnType` is an enum, the Designers property pages will automatically create a drop down of the enums members.No need to decorate the Property with anything else

Comment: Oh wow, I made an enum and yes the drop down appears and displays the enum members! I'm kicking myself right now as it was that simple! Thank you!

Comment: While you are at it, try other enums such as `Color`, `DockStyle`, and `Keys` - Yes, these are all built in ones, but it gives you an idea of what is possible with the designer pages. Also, nesting objects

Comment: I have been tryin them out, can't believe I hadn't before now! Very useful.